# How do I display certain ID and hide the other ID based from a dropdown selection?

Tags: javascript

Please help. I need to show one text field and hide the other text field based from a drop down selection. My problem is that only the first text field is being displayed. Also, the text field does not hide if I do a different selection. Thanks much!!! :)

Here is my script:

```
<script>
function showHide() {
    let MyChoice = document.getElementsByName('xactivitytype');
    if (MyChoice.value = 'SIM Replacement') {
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel2').style.display = 'none';
    } else if (MyChoice.value = 'Change Of Plan') {
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel2').style.display = 'none';
    } else if (MyChoice.value = 'Replacement Of Issued Unit') {
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel2').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel2').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<!--- NEED TO SELECT FIRST HERE ----->
<select name="xcategory" id="dbType" style="font-size:11px;font-family:Tahoma;color:#22215b;font-weight:bold;">
        <option value="Admin">Admin
        <option value="Contractors">Contractors
</select><font color="red">*</font>

<!--- DROPDOWN WILL DEPEND ON THE SELECTION ABOVE ----->
<select onChange=showHide() name="xactivitytype" class="DEPENDS ON xcategory BEING Admin">
        <option value="New Activation">New Activation</option>
        <option value="SIM Replacement">SIM Replacement</option>
        <option value="Change Of Plan">Change Of Plan</option>
        <option value="Transfer To A Regular Account Type">Transfer To A Regular Account Type</option>
        <option value="Replacement Of Issued Unit">Replacement Of Issued Unit</option>
        <option value="Non-Service Related Concerns">Non-Service Related Concerns</option>
</select>
<select onChange=showHide() name="xactivitytype" class="DEPENDS ON xcategory BEING Contractors">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="New Activation/New Handset">New Activation/New Handset</option>
        <option value="SIM Replacement">SIM Replacement</option>
        <option value="Transfer To A Regular Account Type">Transfer To A Regular Account Type</option>
        <option value="Replacement Of Issued Unit">Replacement Of Issued Unit</option>
</select>


<tr id="hidden-panel"><td width="240" align="right" valign="top" style="padding-right:10px;"><b>Service Number:</b></td><td width="750">
    <input type="text" name="xServiceNumber">
</td></tr>
<tr id="hidden-panel2"><td width="240" align="right" valign="top" style="padding-right:10px;"><b>IMSI:</b></td><td width="750">
    <input type="text" name="xIMSI">
</td></tr>
```

CSS:

```
<style>
#hidden-panel {
    display: none;
}
#hidden-panel2 {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

Comment: you might need to disable one of the `select` element based on the selection in `xcategory` otherwise `document.getElementsByName('xactivitytype')` isreturning both 'select' elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 mistakes I see in your code.

1. `let MyChoice = document.getElementsByName('xactivitytype');` Here the getElementsByName method returns an array, so you need to do `document.getElementsByName('xactivitytype')[0]` or `document.getElementsByName('xactivitytype')[1]`
2. In your `if else-if` block you are using assignment operator `=` instead of comparison operator `===`.

Here is an example with the fixes I mentioned.

```js
function showHide() {
    const idx = document.getElementById('dbType').selectedIndex ;
    const MyChoice = document.getElementsByName('xactivitytype')[idx];

    if (MyChoice.value === 'SIM Replacement') {
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel2').style.display = 'none';
    } else if (MyChoice.value === 'Change Of Plan') {
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel2').style.display = 'none';
    } else if (MyChoice.value === 'Replacement Of Issued Unit') {
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel2').style.display = 'block';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('hidden-panel2').style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

```css
<style>
  #hidden-panel {
      display: none;
  }
  #hidden-panel2 {
      display: none;
  }
</style>
```

```html
<!--- NEED TO SELECT FIRST HERE ----->
<select name="xcategory" id="dbType" style="font-size:11px;font-family:Tahoma;color:#22215b;font-weight:bold;">
        <option value="Admin">Admin
        <option value="Contractors">Contractors
</select><font color="red">*</font>

<!--- DROPDOWN WILL DEPEND ON THE SELECTION ABOVE ----->
<select onChange=showHide() name="xactivitytype" class="DEPENDS ON xcategory BEING Admin">
        <option value="New Activation">New Activation</option>
        <option value="SIM Replacement">SIM Replacement</option>
        <option value="Change Of Plan">Change Of Plan</option>
        <option value="Transfer To A Regular Account Type">Transfer To A Regular Account Type</option>
        <option value="Replacement Of Issued Unit">Replacement Of Issued Unit</option>
        <option value="Non-Service Related Concerns">Non-Service Related Concerns</option>
</select>
<select onChange=showHide() name="xactivitytype" class="DEPENDS ON xcategory BEING Contractors">
        <option value="">Please select</option>
        <option value="New Activation/New Handset">New Activation/New Handset</option>
        <option value="SIM Replacement">SIM Replacement</option>
        <option value="Transfer To A Regular Account Type">Transfer To A Regular Account Type</option>
        <option value="Replacement Of Issued Unit">Replacement Of Issued Unit</option>
</select>

<table>
  <tr id="hidden-panel">
    <td width="240" align="right" valign="top" style="padding-right:10px;">
      <b>Service Number:</b></td><td width="750">
      <input type="text" name="xServiceNumber">
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="hidden-panel2">
    <td width="240" align="right" valign="top" style="padding-right:10px;">
      <b>IMSI:</b>
     </td>
     <td width="750">
      <input type="text" name="xIMSI">
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks PR7. I ran your code and is working only on the first selection which is Admin. When I selected Contractors, it didn't display anything. :(

Comment: @francoom I made some changes in the above example. You can check now.

Comment: Also you might want to show only one `xactivitytype`  dropdown at a time. You can add an `onchange` event on `xcategory` dropdown to show/hide the corresponding  `xactivitytype` dropdown.

Comment: Thanks so much PR7 for your help!!! It worked!!! :)

Answer (score 0):

You must use `==` or `===` for comparing values, not just `=`. In your case, you should even use a switch statement.

Answer (score 0):

First you have a problem with equality operator. Notice that `=` is used for assignment and `==` for equality check.

And another problem is that `document.getElementsByName('xactivitytype')` returns `Array of NodeList` And you need to use index to get the value such as:

```
 function showHide() {
        let MyChoice = document.getElementsByName('xactivitytype');
        if (MyChoice[0].value == 'SIM Replacement') {
             ....
        }
    ...
    }
```